# Will increasing server memory help gaining IIS stack memory?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Currently my application have few long running processes. Sometimes IIS getting crash due to `Stack Overflow Exception` while running these processes.

Increasing server spec can really help to solve this problem.

I need some advise on this.

Comment: Nope, stack memory has nothing to do with server memory. However, StackOverflowException usually means you have a problem in your code - it's quite unlikely you'd reach a stack overflow legitimately. Most often, it's caused by a code path that results in infinite recursion. Can you check the stack of the thread where the exception occurred and find the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your advise Luaan. Can you suggest me how to check the stack of thread while executing, is that any tools available to check?

Comment: Well, using WinDbg (with SOS) on a full process dump always works. But most likely, you have all the stack information you need in the exception itself - especially useful with debug symbols. You just need to save the whole exception including the stack trace rather than just the message.